# Available widgets is not showing up?

Tags: theme-development, widgets

[image]

I have added theme support in functions.php file.

```
add_theme_support('widgets');
```

And register the menu still no available default widget.

```
class Sidebars{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->setup_hooks();
    }

    protected function setup_hooks(){
        add_action('widgets_init', [$this, 'register_sidebars']);
    }

    public function register_sidebars(){
        register_sidebar( array(
            'name'          => __( 'Main Sidebar', 'textdomain' ),
            'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
            'description'   => __( 'Widgets in this area will be shown on all posts and pages.', 'textdomain' ),
            'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget'  => '</li>',
            'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
            'after_title'   => '</h2>',
        ) );

    }
}

$sidebar = new Sidebars();
```

[Here is my full code](https://github.com/MdSamsuzzohaShayon/wordpress-theme/tree/7_sport_blog)

I am not an expert but there suppose to have an option of available widgets.
What am I missing?

Comment: Have you pressed the "+" button to add one? Or expanded the Sidebar panels to press the button to add widgets there? Note that this is the Widgets screen in 5.8, which was redesigned to used Blocks, so if you're referencing older screenshots it will not look the same.

Comment: Perhaps you are correct. I just deleted everything and reinstalled WordPress and activated the 2020 theme and that is also behaving the same.

Comment: I am definitely correct: https://wordpress.org/news/2021/08/widgets-in-wordpress-5-8-and-beyond/